# If clause in Jess

Tags: if-statement, jess

Could some one please help me using a if clause in jess, I know the simple sintax but I'm trying to use an && operand so I can use two conditions, but nothing I try seems to work.

```
if((<(?x ?y) && (>=(?z ?s)) then
  ....
else
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jess has a very regular syntax which is quite unlike the Java syntax you're trying to emulate. All "operators" are actually functions, and use the same prefix syntax as function calls.  It's always `(op arg1 arg2 ...)`. The parentheses *always* surround the whole expression, not just the arguments.

So for example, the Java expression `a < b` is always `(< ?a ?b)` in Jess. There is no `&&` operator, but rather, there is an `and` function. So the Java `if (a < b && c > d) ...` looks like `(if (and (< ?a ?b) (> ?c ?s)) then ...` in Jess.